# How to calculate infinitesimal analytic continuation?

Tags: symbolic, pattern-matching, complex, generalized-function

Many problems in science and engineering are related to the analytic continuation and in particular infinitesimal analytic continuation to the upper or lower complex plane, i.e., a generic *complex* function $f(\omega)$ with real $\omega$ is changed to
$$F(\omega)=\lim_{\eta\rightarrow0^+}f(\omega\pm i\eta).$$
In many applications, only the part introduced by $\eta$ is necessary, which is
$$A(\omega)=\lim_{\eta\rightarrow0^+}[f(\omega+i\eta)-f(\omega-i\eta)].$$

**Question**: How to symbolically obtain $A(\omega)$?

A related [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148734) here deals with the simplest case (the first formula below), but I am asking about more general cases when symbolic Fourier transform or integral does not work.

Simple `Limit` does not work, because the [Sokhotski–Plemelj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokhotski%E2%80%93Plemelj_theorem#Version_for_the_real_line) formula
$$\lim_{\eta\to0^{+}} \frac{1}{x\pm i\eta}= \mp i\pi\delta(x) + {\mathcal{P}} {\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)}$$
plays a role in the calculation. Here $\delta$ denotes Dirac delta function (`DiracDelta`), $\mathcal{P}$ denotes the Cauchy principal value. A more general version of this formula is
$$\lim_{\eta\to0^{+}} \frac{1}{(x\pm i\eta)^{n+1}}= \mp i\pi(-1)^n\frac{\delta^{(n)}(x)}{n!} + {\mathcal{P}} {\Big(\frac{1}{x^{n+1}}\Big)}$$
where $\delta^{(n)}$ denotes the $n$-th derivative of $\delta$-function. But note that all these will just appear as convenient symbols, *not* to be evaluated anywhere.

---

Two examples are given below, where all parameters are real. Therefore only the imaginary part is purely generated by $\eta$.
For $f_1(\omega)=\frac{a\omega+\sqrt{c+\omega^2}}{e}$, we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A(\omega)&=2i\lim_{\eta\rightarrow0^+}\Im f(\omega+i\eta)\\
&=2i\lim_{\eta\rightarrow0^+}\Im\frac{a(\omega+i\eta)+\sqrt{c+(\omega+i\eta)^2}}{e}\\
&\approx2i\lim_{\eta\rightarrow0^+}\Im\frac{a(\omega+i\eta)+c+\omega^2+i\eta\frac{\omega}{c+\omega^2}}{e}\\
&=2i\lim_{\eta\rightarrow0^+}\frac{ai\eta+i\eta\frac{\omega}{c+\omega^2}}{e}\\
&=0.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
For $f_2(\omega)=\frac{a+b\omega}{\omega-c}$ we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A(\omega)&=\lim_{\eta\rightarrow0^+} f(\omega+i\eta)-f(\omega-i\eta)\\
&=\lim_{\eta\rightarrow0^+}(a + b c)(\frac{1}{\omega-c+i\eta}-\frac{1}{\omega-c-i\eta})\\
&=[-i\pi\delta(\omega-c)+\mathcal{P}(\frac{1}{\omega-c})]-[+i\pi\delta(\omega-c)+\mathcal{P}(\frac{1}{\omega-c})]\\
&=-2i\pi(a+bc)\delta(\omega-c).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
**Here, simple `Limit` does not work, which merely gives 0 as shown below.**

```
f[ω_] := (a + b ω)/(ω - c);
Limit[f[ω + I η] - f[ω - I η], η -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
```

### Edit

We aim at generic functions $f(\omega)$ that can be more complicated than the above minimal examples, but let's assume the denominator, if `x` is involved, can always be factorized. For instance (use `x` as the variable),

```
f[x_] := (a - b x)/(c^3 + 3 c^2 d + 3 c d^2 + d^3) + Sqrt[x + b]/(
   x - e) + (
   b x + Sqrt[x + b^2])/((x - c)^2 (x - Sqrt[d + c^2]) (x^2 + g^2));
```

In the result, there should be $\delta(x-e),\delta(x-\sqrt{d+c^2}),\delta(x-c),\delta^{(1)}(x-c)$. Also similar

```
f[x_] := (
       b x + Sqrt[x + b^2])/((x - c)^2 (x - Sqrt[d + c^2]+a b^2) (x^2 + g^2))
```

which should give $\delta(x-\sqrt{d+c^2}+a b^2),\delta(x-c),\delta^{(1)}(x-c)$.

I thought about this for some time, but due to my very limited MMA skill, I don't see how to realize such a calculation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142173/discussion-on-question-by-xiaohuamao-how-to-calculate-infinitesimal-analytic-con).

Answer (score 2):

The manual transform can be automated with pattern matching in a straightforward manner:

```
generalLimit[expr_, η_ -> 0] := 
 Limit[expr /. 
   a_. (x_ + c_. Complex[0, i_] η)^n_ :> 
    a (-Complex[0, Sign@i] Pi (-1)^(-1 - n)
         Derivative[-1 - n][δ][x]/(-1 - n)! + \[ScriptCapitalP][
        1/x^-n]), η -> 0]
```

Since you've mentioned that "all these will just appear as convenient symbols, not to be evaluated anywhere", I use `δ` instead of `DiracDelta` so `Simplify`, etc. won't have any effect on it.

I dare not say the `generalLimit` will handle every case, but it does work on the examples in the question:

```
generalLimit[1/(x + I η)^(n + 1), η -> 0]
```

[image]

```
generalLimit[1/(x + I η), η -> 0]
```

[image]

```
generalLimit[ccc/(x + w - 2 y I η), η -> 0]
```

[image]

```
f[ω_] := (a + b ω)/(ω - c);

generalLimit[
  f[ω + I η] - f[ω - I η], η -> 0] // Simplify
```

[image]

And once you've fully understood the definition of `generalLimit`, you should know how to patch it for more complicated cases. To learn more about pattern matching, consider reading posts under [semanic-matching](/questions/tagged/semanic-matching), see also [tips and tricks of Ted Ersek](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/Tricks.html) (Notebook edition is [here](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4557/)).

Comment: Thank you. It does not work for anything without an explicit pattern, e.g., `f[x_] := (a x + Sqrt[c + x^2])/Sqrt[c + x^2]` and `f[x_] := (a x + Sqrt[c + x^2])/(x^2 + 3 x + 2);`. You deleted the text in the question about needing some expansion with respect to $\eta$ first, this is the case (I was worried yesterday maybe you misunderstood the need).  One can expand the denominator to get the desired pattern.

Comment: @xiaohuamao 1. Try `Apart`. 2. If you think series expansion is related, you should give a concrete example based on series expansion.

Comment: I was about to add such an example but you deleted the description before I did so. So I felt OK let's see maybe you have a cleverer method... Also, my first example is actually based on such expansion, but maybe not general enough. Anyway, certainly not to blame anyone!

Comment: @xiaohuamao The first example is a bad example, because `Limit` gives the same output, too. "Anyway, certainly not to blame anyone! " No, you're the one to blame. As a member for 9 years, you should have done a better job in asking a question.

Comment: I accept your critique.

Comment: Thanks for the earlier communications. I thought about this more carefully and realized that expansion, although doable, is not quite the efficient way. So I updated the example. Apart does work in its own role, but the present code misses $\delta(x-\sqrt{d+c^2})$ and introduces spurious $\delta^{(-\frac{3}{2})}$ from the nominator. If we change the denominator $\frac{1}{x-\sqrt{d+c^2}}$ to $\frac{1}{x-a-\sqrt{d+c^2}}$, running the code becomes even weirder including computation complexity, but I notice that it treats similar $\frac{1}{x-a-b(p+q^2)}$ very easily.